# How to add checkall and uncheck all option for jquery multiselect?

Tags: jquery, html

I have added jquery multiselect property for my dropdown. Dropdown is like this,

```
<div>
<select id="selectChartType" multiple="multiple" size="5" style="width:25px" >
      <option value="option1">option1</option>
      <option value="option2">option2</option>
      <option value="option3">option3</option>
      <option value="option4">option4</option>
      <option value="option5">option5</option>
      <option value="option6">option6</option>
      <option value="option7">option7</option>
      <option value="option8">option8</option>
      <option value="option9">option9</option>
      <option value="option10">option10</option>
</select>
</div>
```

I am initializing multiselect like this,

```
$(document).ready(function() {
     $("#selectChartType").multiselect({
     header:false,
     noneSelectedText:"options",
     minWidth: 190
      });
});
```

I want 2 options inside the dropdown saying checkall and uncheckall. I know there is a option,

```
$("#selectChartType").multiselect({CheckAll});
```

But i don't know how to add it in html. Please help me

Comment: Please setup a http://jsfiddle.net/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should use something like this for jquery

**JQuery**

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    $("#checkAll").click(function(){

        $('#selectChartType option').prop('selected', true);
    });
    $("#unCheckAll").click(function(){

        $('#selectChartType option').prop('selected', false);

     });
});
```

And add button in **HTML** as

```
<div>
    <select id="selectChartType" multiple="multiple" size="5" style="width:250px" >
          <option value="option1">option1</option>
          <option value="option2">option2</option>
          <option value="option3">option3</option>
          <option value="option4">option4</option>
          <option value="option5">option5</option>
          <option value="option6">option6</option>
          <option value="option7">option7</option>
          <option value="option8">option8</option>
          <option value="option9">option9</option>
          <option value="option10">option10</option>
    </select>
</div>
<input type="button" id="checkAll" value="check all">
<input type="button" id="unCheckAll" value="Un-check all">
```

you can see [Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/themohanahuja/a5w3C/1/) here.

and I guess you are using some of multi-select plugin then you might want to check their doc or let us know which plugin you are using to help you more with that.

Answer (score 0):

**More Interesting :**

```
<div>
<select id="selectChartType" multiple="multiple" size="5">
      <option value="all">Select All</option>
      <option value="option1">option1</option>
      <option value="option2">option2</option>
      <option value="option3">option3</option>
      <option value="option4">option4</option>

</select>
</div>
$(document).ready(function(){

    var clicker=0;
    $("#selectChartType option[value='all']").click(function(e){
        clicker++;
        $(this).prop('selected', false);
        if(clicker%2!=0){


        $("#selectChartType option[value!='all']").prop('selected', true);
        }
       else
        $("#selectChartType option[value!='all']").prop('selected', false);

     });
});
```

[FIDDLE DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/6M5V2/)

Answer (score 0):

You can initialize by

```
**$(document).ready(function() {
 $("#selectChartType").multiselect({
 header:true, /* Contains CHeck all and Uncheck all */
 noneSelectedText:"options",
 minWidth: 190
  });
```

});**

Regards
Krishna Kumar S

Answer (score 0):

```
//Uncheck all Options
        var selected = $("#sectorId option:selected");
        var totaloptions = $("#selectChartType option");
        if (selected.length == totaloptions.length) {

            $('.ms-selectall').trigger('click');
        }
        else {
            $('.ms-selectall').trigger('click');
            $('.ms-selectall').trigger('click');
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Check and uncheck multiselect input with a Checkbox using Jquery.

My solution:

```js
// jquery 
$( document ).ready(function() { 
    
  $('#check_uncheck').click(function() {      
        var chk = $('#check_uncheck').is(':checked'); 
        if (chk==false)
            $('#selectChartType option').prop('selected', false);
        else
            $('#selectChartType option').prop('selected', true);
   });
    
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="banner-message">
  <p>Check and Uncheck a Multiselect input with a Checkbox</p>
  <input type="checkbox" name="check_uncheck" id="check_uncheck">
  <div class="none">
    <select  id="selectChartType" name="selectChartType" multiple>
      <option value="1">Option 1</option>
      <option value="2">Option 2</option>
      <option value="3">Option 3</option>
      <option value="4">Option 4</option>
      <option value="5">Option 5</option>         
    <select/>
 </div>  
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
$('#multiple-checkboxes').multiselect({
  includeSelectAllOption: true,
});
```

Use this code for adding checkall and uncheck all option for jquery multiselect